# Is the oscillation of all particles for stationary wave equal?

Tags: waves

Is the oscillation of all particles for stationary wave equal? I think the point of nodes for stationary wave never oscilliate. Is this idea true?

Comment: Assuming you mean a standing wave, then you are quite correct. The particles at a node are stationary.

Comment: http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Standing_wave.gif